# Dont know how to sort a field in unix

Tags: shell, unix

How to sort a field which has large number of file size in that field.
for eg

> 407 k file
>
> 45M j file
>
> 4.5M l file

here to sort in largest order

Comment: Oops, You forgot to post your code. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding (or cmd-line option spec) service. Any code is better than no code at all. Good luck.

Comment: Instead of trying to sort information which is very difficult to read, I'd advise you to get the input standardised: try to get all information in bytes, and then try to do a `sort -n`.

Comment: With [GNU sort](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/sort.1.html), you'll use the `-h` option.

Comment: thank you all.. i got the output